# creating a factor-based in dendrogram with R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, hierarchical-clustering

This is not so much a coding as general approach call for help ;-) I prepared a table containing taxonomic information about organisms. But I want to use the "names" of these organisms, so no values or anything where you could compute a distance or clustering with (this is also all the information I have). I just want to use these factors to create a plot that shows the relationship. My data looks like this:

```
    test2<-structure(list(genus = structure(c(4L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 5L), .Label = c("Aminobacter", "Bradyrhizobium", "Hoeflea", 
"Hyphomonas", "Mesorhizobium", "Methylosinus", "Ochrobactrum", 
"uncultured"), class = "factor"), family = structure(c(4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Bradyrhizobiaceae", 
"Brucellaceae", "Hyphomicrobiaceae", "Hyphomonadaceae", "Methylocystaceae", 
"Phyllobacteriaceae"), class = "factor"), order = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Caulobacterales", 
"Rhizobiales"), class = "factor"), class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Alphaproteobacteria", class = "factor"), 
    phylum = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Proteobacteria", class = "factor")), .Names = c("genus", 
"family", "order", "class", "phylum"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
9L))
```

is it necessary to set up artificial values to describe a distance between the levels?

Comment: @missuse: hope I got it fixed, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an attempt using data.tree library

First create a string variable in the form:
`Proteobacteria/Alphaproteobacteria/Caulobacterales/Hyphomonadaceae/Hyphomonas`

```
library(data.tree)
test2$pathString <- with(test2, 
                               paste(phylum,
                                     class,
                                     order,
                                     family,
                                     genus, sep = "/"))

tree_test2 = as.Node(test2)
plot(tree_test2)
```

[image]

many things can be done after like:

Interactive network:

```
library(networkD3)
test2_Network <- ToDataFrameNetwork(tree_test2, "name")
simpleNetwork(test2_Network)
```

[image]

or graph styled

```
library(igraph)
plot(as.igraph(tree_test2, directed = TRUE, direction = "climb"))
```

check out the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html)

[image]

using ggplot2:

```
library(ggraph)
graph = as.igraph(tree_test2, directed = TRUE, direction = "climb")

ggraph(graph, layout = 'kk') + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name))+
  geom_edge_link(arrow = arrow(type = "closed", ends = "first",
                               length = unit(0.20, "inches"),
                               angle = 15)) +
  geom_node_point() +
  theme_graph()+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-3,3), expand = TRUE)
```

[image]

or perhaps:

```
ggraph(graph, layout = 'kk') + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name),   repel = T)+
  geom_edge_link(angle_calc = 'along',
                 end_cap = circle(3, 'mm'))+ 
  geom_node_point(size = 5) +
  theme_graph()+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-3,3), expand = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: that looks really cool, I will try to play around with the data. Do you know if the data.tree object can be imported somehow to ggplot2? I would like to try different shapes and forms regarding the lines etc

Comment: Edited with an example using `ggraph` library.

Comment: Using a bigger dataset, I'm running into trouble creating the igraph. igraph tells me that "Node names must be unique within the tree". I will dig into the manuals to see what is causing this, as I tried to remove possible duplicates (data.tree works fine, though). Thanks for the great examples!

Comment: The basic `plot` method of `data.tree` is quite flexible  you can look into that if having problems with `igraph`. Or perhaps nail the problem to a subset of the data and post another question on SO.

Comment: that is a good idea. I fixed the problem now, but new ones are appearing ;-) so I will see how far I can get already with the base plot. Thank you!